# Moved files on mirror drive

Tags: hard-drive, mirroring

I have two external drives that were identical mirrors of each other. Then, one drive had some files moved around. No new files, just moved to new folder locations.

Is there an easy way to bring these two drives back into sync? WinMerge will do it, but it is copying large chunks of data from one from to the other, when all the files already exist on both drives.

I don't think robocopy can handle this. Maybe I need a piece of software that will analyze each drive and then do a backup of the changed drive?

Thanks

Comment: Sync Back Pro will do this. //i have used it for years.

Comment: Do you know what files were moved? How were the drives mirrored previously? Both these may have an impact on the best way to get things back into order.

Comment: I know what files were moved, but it’s too many to list. Files were taken from multiple locations and moved to one location. The drives were previously mirrored using WinMerge, the first drive just copied over to the second.